# Unknown property in v-for using Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to understand the `v-for` concept in Vue JS and I am very new to this framework.

I am using Django, that's why I am using custom delimiters. I have an example script that adds a list of objects to a data property:

```js
var app = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        loading: true,
        datasetFilesArray: null
    },
    methods: {
        datasetFiles: function () {
            axios.get('api/list_all_data')
                .then(response => {
                    this.loading = false;

                    this.datasetFilesArray = response.data;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                });
        }
    },
    beforeMount() {
        this.datasetFiles()
    }
});
```

Initially `datasetFilesArray` is null, but once the response is received, the null is replaced by an object.

When I try to use this in HTML tags as:

```html
...
<tr v-for="content in datasetFilesArray">
    <th class="align-middle">
        <a href="">[[content.file_name]]</a>
    </th>
    <th class="align-middle">[[content.date]]</th>
</tr>
...
```

I am getting an error saying that `Property or method "content" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.` But everything works fine when I add `content` to `data` do:

```js
...
data: {
    loading: true,
    datasetFilesArray: null
    content: null
},
...
```

But the example shown in https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object, the `value` keyword has not been initialised and it looks like its working.

Am I doing something wrong?

**Update**

I thought this might take the property from the `meta` as `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">` tag so I changed it from `content` to `datasetItems` and I still get the same error.

**Update 2**

Example of my page https://codepen.io/akshaybabloo/pen/ExxexxE

If you see the developers tool, you will get to see the error I was talking about

Comment: try to initialize yours arrays like `datasetFilesArray:[]`

Comment: Is that snippet the only place you're using `content` in the template?

Comment: @DecadeMoon yes

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim will do. Thanks. +1

Comment: @Akshay and you don't need `content` to be declared in data object

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim If I don't do that I am getting an error as - Property or method "content" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

Comment: As a fail safe you could have a `v-if="datasetFilesArray.length > 0"` over parent of iterating `<tr>`. And `content` definitely doesn't need to be in `data` property

Comment: @Akshay You also need to be clear with your question; you give a variable name `datasetFilesArray`, but then you say this variable is an object.  While the argument could be made that every datatype in js is an object, there is still a large difference between the two types(object/array) for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** This looks suspicious to me:

```html
<tr v-for="content in datasetFilesArray">
    [[content]]
```

You cannot have text directly as a child of a `<tr>` element, it needs to be in a `<td>` or a `<th>`, otherwise it'll be pushed outside of the `<tr>` (see my comment about HTML tables below).

Essentially the DOM ends up like this *before* Vue compiles the template:

```html
[[content]]
<tr v-for="content in datasetFilesArray">
```

Clearly `content` is being used outside of its scope, so instead it is looked up as a property of the component instance (the generated render function is wrapped in a [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement, which explains this magic), and since `content` is not defined on the component Vue raises this warning. You then declared `content` inside the `data` property of the component, so now it is defined, but all that did was squelch the warning, further complicating the situation.

Try this instead:

```html
<tr v-for="content in datasetFilesArray">
    <th>[[content]]</th>
```

Lastly, I suggest you read [Why You Should Avoid Vue.js DOM Templates](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/09/17/vue-js-avoid-dom-templates/) for more information about this.

---

It isn't clear from what you have provided what the cause of the error is. Can you provide a fiddle?

The error indicates that `content` is not declared within the scope it is used in the template. It is declared by the `v-for`, so any usage of `content` within the `<tr>` should be valid. If you are using `content` anywhere else in the template then that could be a cause of this error.

Also check your javascript code to see if you are accessing `this.content` anywhere, especially by methods or computed properties that can be executed from within the template.

Tables can be finicky in HTML; sometimes the elements will be auto-closed by the browser when the table is not marked up correctly. See if the error persists after you change `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<th>` and `<td>` to `<div>`. It would help if you can provide your complete HTML.

Comment: I am on it. Sorry

Comment: Oh! got it, I was just trying to check if the content was working or not. Thanks for your help!

Comment: But I wonder why it was working when the `content` was initialised